# npm install: Is there a way to ignore a particular dependency in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, package.json

I am currently trying to create a docker container for a node.js project that contains a local dependency.  This seems to cause an issue with docker so as a workaround I am trying to just copy the local dependency folders and just ignore their dependency entries in the package.json file.  Is there a way to specify dependencies I would like to ignore and have npm install run and skip those enties?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That can be done using [devDependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#devdependencies)

The npm modules which you require only to develop, e.g.: unit tests, Coffeescript to Javascript transpilation, minification etc,make the required module a devDependency.

To skip Installation of devDepenencies pass `--production` flag to `npm install`,with the `--production` flag(or `NODE_ENV` environment variable set to `production`) `npm` will not install modules listed in devDependencies."

```
npm install --production
```

To make any module to be part of devDependencies pass --dev while installing.

```
npm install packagename --save-dev
```

Comment: This does not help if you actually need the dev dependencies (eg for testing) but you want to ignore one

Comment: Any solution that doesn't involve using yarn? This answer assumes the dependency is an actual dev only dependency, which isn't always the case.

Answer (score 3):

It is a common issue, not only with Docker, but also with some cloud deployments. For example deployment to CloudFoundry using standard Node.js buildpack will cause `npm install`/`yarn` to run anyway. So, you'll also need to apply some tricks to work with local modules

If you don't mind to switch from NPM to Yarn for dependency management, you can use [workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/) feature.

My `package.json` looks like this:

```
{

  ...

  "dependencies": {
    "some-module-i-want-to-install": "1.0.0",
    "another-module-i-want-to-install": "1.0.0",
    "@my/local-dependency-one": "1.0.0",
    "@my/local-dependency-two": "1.0.0"
  },
  "workspaces": ["packages/*"]
}
```

And my project source layout has the following structure:

```
.
├── index.js
├── package.json
├── packages
│   ├── local-dependency-one
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   └── package.json
│   └── local-dependency-two
│       ├── index.js
│       └── package.json
└── yarn.lock
```

After running `yarn`, modules I want to install are fetched from NPM registry, and local dependencies are installed from `packages` directory to `node_modules`.

```
.
├── index.js
├── node_modules
│   ├── @my
│   │   ├── local-dependency-one
│   │   │   └── ...
│   │   └── local-dependency-two
│   │       └── ...
│   ├── another-module-i-want-to-install
│   │   └── ...
│   └── some-module-i-want-to-install
│       └── ...
├── package.json
├── packages
│   ├── local-dependency-one
│   │   └── ...
│   └── local-dependency-two
│       └── ...
└── yarn.lock
```

As you can see, I prefer to define my local packages as [scoped](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-scopes) (`@my/...`). It is not mandatory, but a best practice. NPM treats scoped packages as [private by default](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-scopes#scopes-and-package-visibility), so I don't need to worry that they will be occasionally published or explicitly mark them as private.

Comment: never versions of npm also have a workspace feature:
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/workspaces?v=true