# Updating npm: Cannot find module 'y18n' npm ERR?

Tags: node.js, npm

I did not update npm for a while. My version is 5.8.0
the current is 6.4.1

I tried this command, but did not work:

```
$ npm install npm@latest -g
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm ERR! Cannot find module 'y18n'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\erjan222\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-09-16T14_16_55_797Z-debug.log
```

Googling for similar topic on npm forum did not help -
[y18-n](https://npm.community/t/cannot-find-module-y18n/742/8)

The debug.log file has this:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\erjan222\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'npm@latest',
1 verbose cli   '-g' ]
2 info using npm@5.8.0
3 info using node@v8.10.0
4 verbose stack Error: Cannot find module 'y18n'
4 verbose stack     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
4 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
4 verbose stack     at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
4 verbose stack     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
4 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\erjan222\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\cacache\lib\util\y.js:4:14)
4 verbose stack     at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
4 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
4 verbose stack     at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
4 verbose stack     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
4 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
4 verbose stack     at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
4 verbose stack     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
4 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\erjan222\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\cacache\lib\entry-index.js:13:11)
4 verbose stack     at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
4 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
4 verbose stack     at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
5 verbose cwd C:\Users\erjan222\Desktop
6 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
7 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\erjan222\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "npm@latest" "-g"
8 verbose node v8.10.0
9 verbose npm  v5.8.0
10 error code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
11 error Cannot find module 'y18n'
12 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend that you try install y18n first then upgrade npm like this:

```
npm install y18n@4.0.0 -g
npm install npm@latest -g
```

Or install 8.12.0 LTS from [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

Comment: i completely deleted & reinstalled the node & npm, this worked, but still giving u some +50 rep points

Answer (score 2):

First, upgrade your npm to latest version and Then install `y18n` module  using this commands
 
`npm i -g npm-upgrade`
`npm i y18n`

If you want to ignore particular module from **npm update**,refer this link answer.
[npm install: Is there a way to ignore a particular dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47374072/npm-install-is-there-a-way-to-ignore-a-particular-dependency-in-package-json)