# npm install doesn't work @idwall-sdk-capacitor

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, ionic-framework

[404 error message picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGqYk.png)

Basically, i'm trying to run a `npm install`, but this package doesn't exist anymore
and with that, i'm not able to install the other dependencies of the project

Is there any way to ignore this issue and be able to `run npm install` without this package?

I tried to run a `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`, but this doesn't work as well, so, i'm not able to install my dependencies

I tried a lot of things already, but nothing is working

Comment: if you can do without the library, you can uninstall it [Uninstalling packages and dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/uninstalling-packages-and-dependencies) `npm uninstall @idwall-sdk-capacitor`

Comment: or you can try this link: [npm install: Is there a way to ignore a particular dependency in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47374072/npm-install-is-there-a-way-to-ignore-a-particular-dependency-in-package-json)